# End to end security with WMQ AMS

Tags: security, encryption, jms, ibm-mq, websphere-mq-ams

I have to encrypt messages with WMQ Advanced Message Security.  What do I need to do in my program or .bindings file to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news - there is nothing to do in your code or .bindings file.  WMQ AMS uses interceptors to catch the API calls before they are handed to WMQ.  The configuration is entirely external to your program and consists of using an environment variable to point to an ini file.  The ini file in turn points to the keystore which can be a jks or IBM's kdb format (such as that used by QMgrs).

The various quick start guides outline the steps required to get AMS up and running.

- [Quick Start Guide for WebSphere MQ AMS on UNIX platforms](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q014700_.htm)
- [Quick Start Guide for WebSphere MQ AMS on Windows platforms](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q014690_.htm)
- [Quick Start Guide for WebSphere MQ AMS with Java clients](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q014710_.htm)